# Run macro if date time values in a column changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date/time column in an excel sheet (yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss) that can be updated.  I have several VBA functions I want to run only if any of the date values in this column changes.

Right I record the dates in another sheet and then compare the two columns.  I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it.  Thanks

Comment: Are there **formulas** in the cells or **constants** entered by hand ??

Comment: no formula's just a date in the format of yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss